# outputting the doc file in django

Tags: python, django

I want to output the result in to doc file. I am already getting the result in pdf
using

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources )
```

I want the alternative code for above in python-docx. Please provide any links which gives the detailed example of python docx.
But the same file is getting open in libra office. I dont know how.
I used

```
report_mail(request,result,email,message)
            response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.docx'
            return response
```

getting output as file.docx also. But its not getting open in ms office professional 2010.
I am getting the error "The file can not be open because there are problems with the content  details:- The file is corrupt and can not be open"

and for

```
content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.doc'
```

getting raw data in file like

```
%PDF-1.4
%“Œ‹ž ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
% 'BasicFonts': class PDFDictionary 
1 0 obj
% The standard fonts dictionary
<< /F1 2 0 R
 /F2 3 0 R >>
endobj
% 'F1': class PDFType1Font 
2 0 obj
% Font Helvetica
<< /BaseFont /Helvetica
 /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
 /Name /F1
 /Subtype /Type1
 /Type /Font >>
endobj
```

Please help me out for this problem.

Comment: is anyone there who can answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Pisa is a tool for converting HTML to PDF. It reads a html source and delivers a pdf file. That is what you get. So far so good.

Changing the file name extension from `.pdf` to `.doc` or `.docx` doesn't change its content. You're lucky that LibreOffice is able to open pdf files. Microsoft Office is not.

Creating a `docx` with `python-docx` is not the same as using `pisa` to get a pdf. Again: `pisa` converts html to pdf, `python-docx` doesn't convert html to docx. This requires more steps.

According to the [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) documentation you need to work with a `Document` object like this:

```
from docx import Document
[...]

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
[...]
document.save('demo.docx')
```

You need to add content to your document, step by step.